# How to use kerning between two fonts in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, kerning

I would like to add appropriate kerning between two fonts.  Specifically, I currently have (two examples):

```css
div.hw_count {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div.hw_count p {
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 80px;
}
div.hw_count_separator {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
div.hw_count_separator p {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hw_count"><p>1</p></div>
<div class="hw_count_separator"><p>x</p></div>

<span style=padding:20px></span> <!-- just to space examples apart -->

<div class="hw_count"><p>2</p></div>
<div class="hw_count_separator"><p>x</p></div>
```

The issue is I'd like the spacing between the number and the 'x' to appear similar for all digits.  It clearly looks greater for the number '1' (and sometimes appears even more distinct when I change font weight/family/style).

I don't suspect there is any way to do some magical kerning given that in my example the digit and 'x' are in different `div`s.  But, is there any simple CSS-only way to decrease the right blank space appropriately for the given font/digit?

My only solution right now would be to tweak with javascript for each digit (I likely only have to tweak for digit '1').  However, I suspect this may break if I change fonts - I'd hate to have to re-tweak.

Comment: can you use spans for inline elements instead of divs?

Comment: There isn't a catch-all solution as this is an issue with the font itself, rather than CSS. Your best bet is to take a look at the `letter-spacing` property.

Comment: @DanielA.White think I could use spans, or worst case, two spans within a div.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin letter-spacing is what I was going to use, but with javascript, arbitrarily chosen per digit.

Comment: Did you try `font-kerning: off`?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr;** probably not worth the effort in code, I'd just apply a class for that special instance or search for the element by content, in jQuery it might look like `$('.hw_count p:contains("1")');` and set a special class for that.

Actual text metrics are a little elusive. Using the most precise tool we have at our disposal, canvas, even then you can only consistently get width (without a library). But, width is the same for characters that are thinner than a certain dimension (this is a characteristic of the font family). The width of "1" and "2" are the same in in the fonts I tested: Arial, Verdana, and Times: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrjxQM

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.font = '80px Arial';

var text = ctx.measureText("1");
console.log('1: ' + text.width);

text = ctx.measureText("2");
console.log('2: ' + text.width);

text = ctx.measureText("M");
console.log('M: ' + text.width);

text = ctx.measureText("10");
console.log('10: ' + text.width);
```

The above code yields:

```
1: 44.4921875
2: 44.4921875
M: 66.640625
10: 88.984375
```

The attributes that might help are actualBoundingBoxRight and actualBoundingBoxLeft but those are only experimentally supported in Chrome:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextMetrics and even then, I suspect they will report the same as above.

You might also try a library like http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Text.html or a pure JS solution as demonstrated here http://galacticmilk.com/journal/2011/01/html5-typographic-metrics/#measure all of which would likely report and calculate based on the same "bounding box" that exists around the characters.

You might also be able to produce an image from a canvas, then measure the actual pixels but, that's so much work for a little gain.